C# fluent pattern for nested if conditions
I am working in C#. And I have a scenario as shown here:
var response1 = service.AddSchool(object model, string a);

if (response1.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    var response2 = service.AddTeacher(object model, int a, string b);
    
    if (response2.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        var response3 = service.AddStudent(object model, int a, int b, string c);
        
        if (response3.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var response4 = service.AddSubject(object model, string a);
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}

I have nested if conditions where if I am getting HttpStatusCode "OK" I am calling other method. But I wanted to change this nested if condition with Fluent Pattern.
Can anyone suggest how we can do that? I tried extension methods.

I'm sure this is just a typo as your redacting your code, but you don't put type names when you call a method (Func3(model, ... not Func3(object model, ...). Where does model, a, and b come from? Do you do anything with each of the responses other than check their status code?

if status code is  'OK' we are calling other api and if its not 'OK' we are returning false from api. And the model,a and b are coming from input provides by user.

these parameters - model, a or b etc are dynamic and their type could be anything.

I'm not sure what you mean by "fluent" in this situation. Could you give an example of what you'd like to see, even if that's pseudo code? You could always do if (resp1.StatusCode != OK) return false; to exit early and not nest, but I don't know if that fits into what you're looking for.

@gunr2171,I wanted to remove this nested if condition and in place of that I want some cleaner code (like method chaining). But method chaining on the basis of output of previous method.

This looks like a pattern where you return null when you should just throw an exception if it's not ok. Sure, the not ok response could be 404 not found, but it could also be 500 server error or 401 not authorized, which would need a different fix. If the service throws on a failed request, you can just call the functions sequentially. In general, you want to make a dedicated class for calling APIs to handle the specific responses and return the API response. You're mixing the business logic of using the API with its implementation details.

Since there are no elses for compenstation handling, I'd just make sure all these methods throw and then I'd put try-catch over a simple block of calling one after the other.

If nesting is your only issue - you can avoid fluent designs or extensions or another kind of overengineering by simple condition negation, which keeps your code pretty readable and understandable:
public bool CreateAndFillSchool()
{
    Predicate<Response> requestSuccessful =
        response => response is { StatusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK };

    if (!requestSuccessful(service.AddSchool(...))
    {
        LogSomehow("Failed to add school");
        return false;
    }

    if (!requestSuccessful(service.AddTeacher(...))
    {
        LogSomehow("Failed to add teacher");
        return false;
    }

    // another AddSomeone() or AddSomething()...

    return true;
}

While your conditions are dependent (like Teacher can't be added if School wasn't added previously), such multiple negations help to keep the proper calling order as well. But if you still want have fluent design and also be ensured that your calls properly ordered - you have to implement some small overengineering through almost common Fluent Builder pattern with various number of fluent interfaces:
public interface ISchoolBuilder
{
    ISchool AddSchool(...);
}

public interface ISchool : ICreationResult
{
    ITeacher AddTeacher(...);
}

public interface ITeacher : ICreationResult
{
    ICreationResult AddStudent(...);
}

public interface ICreationResult
{
    bool GetResult();
}

public class SchoolBuilder : 
    ISchoolBuilder,
    ISchool,
    ITeacher
{
    private Service _service;
    private bool _result;
    private readonly Predicate<Response> _isRequestSuccessful =
        response => response is { StatusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK };
    
    // Hiding constructor to disallow direct interaction with 'SchoolBuilder'...    
    private SchoolBuilder() { }
    
    // ... instead creating instance through static method and returning it via necessary interface
    public static ISchoolBuilder New() => new SchoolBuilder();
    
    // As we require some outer dependency, which performs additions,
    // we inject it through such method.
    // Can be removed, while 'service' can be passed through 'New()' above
    public ISchoolBuilder? UseService(Service service)
    {
        _service = service;
        return _service is not null ? this : null;
    }
    
    // Adding school and returning current builder via interface, which should continue fluent chain
    public ISchool? AddSchool(...)
    {   
        _result = _isRequestSuccessful(_service.AddSchool(...));
        return _result ? this : null;
    }

    // 
    public ITeacher? AddTeacher(...)
    {
        _result = _isRequestSuccessful(_service.AddTeacher(...));
        return _result ? this : null;
    }
    
    // 'ICreationResult' return type means that method supposed to be last in chain of additions
    // and the only next step is getting the result
    public ICreationResult AddStudent(...)
    {
        _result =  _isRequestSuccessful(_service.AddStudent(...));
        return this;
    }
    
    public bool GetResult() => _result;
}
    

and such builder can be used in such way:
public bool CreateAndFillSchool()
{
    var schoolCreated = SchoolBuilder.New()
            .UseService(service)? // Null-check as service may not be provided
            .AddSchool(...)? // Null-check as adding School may fail
            .AddTeacher(...)? // Null-check as adding Teacher may fail
            .AddStudent(...) // No null-checks as herr we ensured that School and Teacher was added
            .GetResult();

    return schoolCreated is true; // as because of null-checks 'schoolCreated' is nullable boolean ('bool?')
}

The point of such approach is to make single class be represented to consumer via interfaces, while each specific interface allows only specific action (School can add Teacher, Teacher can add Student, but Student can't add School and Teacher can't be accessed without School, etc.). "Prevention" of access to next call in chain implemented through returning of null if some action was unsuccessful, so that you supposed to use null-coalecsings ?. in call chain (or you will catch an exception).
Check complete demo: fiddle. Switch "responses" returned from Service to see different results. Feel free to ask if something remains uncleared.

Another alternative. Not Fluent, but concise and readable...
Func<Response,bool> IsOk = response => response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;

return IsOk(service.AddSchool(model, a))
        && IsOk(service.AddTeacher(model, a, b))
        && IsOk(service.AddStudent(model, a, b, c))
        && IsOk(service.AddSubject(model, a));


somehow its working.

Of course it is working!

I feel like you're trying to get to a fluent chaining of calls like:
service.AddSchool(school)
       .AddTeacher(teacher)
       .AddStudent(student)
       .AddSubject(subject)

Which looks very clean and is very possible if you think about things like:

What does AddSchool return? Does it echo back the service so you can just call AddTeacher on it? Does it return the school that knows how to add related teacher in the repository? Or do you use some sort of abstraction that has context about what the previous method did (i.e. an encapsulation of the Service object and the School object)
Suppose there is a failure at one level - how does the user know which statement failed? Do you just handle the exception and look at the stack trace?

I'll admit I don't have a lot of experience designing fluent interfaces, so maybe these questions are elementary, but there's nothing "built-in" to C# that answers these type of questions for you or magically provides the framework for fluent method chaining.

@D Stanley, these methods (AddSchool, AddTeacher, AddStudent) will return HttpStatusCode Like(200, 401,400 etc). And we need to check if its returning statuscode == 200 then we need to call other API. And if its not returning StatusCode == 200 at anytime we need to return false.


I tried extension methods.

You could do it with extension methods like this:
public class Response {
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
}

public static class Extensions {
    // more flexible
    public static Response GetNextResponseIf(this Response response, Func<Response, bool> predicate, Func<Response> func) {
        if (response == null) return null;
        if (predicate(response)) return func();
        return null;
    }

    // IfOkay
    public static Response GetNextResponseIfOkay(this Response response, Func<Response> func) {
        if (response == null) return null;
        if (response.StatusCode == 200) return func();
        return null;
    }
}

then use:
var response = new Response() { StatusCode = 200 };
Func<Response, bool> predicate = r => r.StatusCode == 200; // for reuse
var finalResponse = response
        .GetNextResponseIf(x => x.StatusCode == 200,() => new Response() { StatusCode = 404 }) //inline predicate
        .GetNextResponseIf(predicate, () => new Response() { StatusCode = 200 }) // no NullReferenceException because we do that on extension methods (static)
        .GetNextResponseIfOkay(() => new Response() { StatusCode = 200 });
if(finalResponse==null) return false;
return true;

